# Angular 7, chart.js even when chart replaced, remaining chart in background which appears sometimes when mouseover

Tags: chart.js, angular7

With angular 7, I integrated a chart.js for days of electricity charges. And in various part of my application I have similar charts which load with next/previous day button, etc.

When recreating the chart (on any next or previous day clicked) I do basically following

```
this.mainChart = new Chart('idOfCanvasOnHtmlComponent', {....})
this.mainChart.update()
```

It seems that it **remains the old chart(s)** which is sometimes showed on `mouseover` on some points and appears strangely, like there are multiple charts which are loaded on `mouseover` which is anoying!

### ChargeUnitDailyComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDatepickerInputEvent } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MiscHelper } from 'src/app/helpers/MiscHelper';
import { ChargeUnitService } from 'src/app/services/charge.unit.service';
import { ChargeUnit } from 'src/app/entities/charge.unit';
import { UserMessage, UserMessageType } from 'src/app/entities/user.message';
import { MessageService } from 'src/app/services/message.service';
import { Constants } from 'src/app/Constants';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import Chart = require('chart.js')
import { MeasuringPoint } from 'src/app/entities/measuring.point';
import { MeasuringPointService } from 'src/app/services/measuring.point.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-charge-unit-daily',
templateUrl: './charge-unit-daily.component.html',
styleUrls: [
    './charge-unit-daily.component.css',
    '../../entities-list.component.css'
]
})

export class ChargeUnitDailyComponent implements AfterContentInit {

static readonly CHART_ID = 'canvasDaily'

currentDate: Date = moment('2019-03-06T00:00:01').toDate() //set default here
/** Header */
dateFormControl = new FormControl(this.currentDate)
statusMessage = 'Default status'
refreshButtonDisabled: boolean = false
/** CHART */
mainChart: Chart;
protected loadingDate: Date = new Date()

constructor(
    iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    protected messageService: MessageService,
    protected entitiesService: ChargeUnitService,
    protected parentService: MeasuringPointService,
) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'refresh',
    sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/refresh-icon.svg'));
    //Do nothing
}

public ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => { //to avoid error...
    if (this.parentService.currentEntity == null){
        this.parentService.currentEntity = new MeasuringPoint(7) //TODO: remove me
    }
    console.debug('currentDate 1 :', this.currentDate)
    this.setChart(this.currentDate)
    this.dateFormControl.setValue(this.currentDate)
    }, 10);

    // this.setStatus('Default canvas...', true)
}//End ngOnInit



/**
*
* @param aDate
*/
protected setChart(aDate: Date){
    let lStartDate = new Date(aDate)
    lStartDate.setHours(0)
    lStartDate.setMinutes(0)
    lStartDate.setSeconds(1)

    let lEndDate = new Date(aDate)
    lEndDate.setHours(23)
    lEndDate.setMinutes(59)
    lEndDate.setSeconds(59)
    this.setStatus('Loading...', false)
    this.loadingDate = new Date()
    console.debug('----- setChart->aDate:', aDate)
    this.resetChart()

    this.entitiesService.getBetween(lStartDate, lEndDate).subscribe(
    lData => {
        console.debug('Received data from entitiesService:', lData);
        let lDataArray = (lData as unknown) as []
        let lChargeUnitsArray: ChargeUnit[] = []
        lDataArray.forEach(element => {
        lChargeUnitsArray.push(new ChargeUnit().deserialize(element))
        })
        this.setChartDataFromEntities(lStartDate, lChargeUnitsArray)
    },
    lError => {
        this.messageService.add(new UserMessage('charge-unit-daily.component->setChart Error:', lError, UserMessageType.Error));
        this.setStatus('Error loading chart data:' + lError.toString(), true)
    },
    () => {
        //loading terminated
    }
    );

}

onDateChanged(anEventType: string, anEvent: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date> ) {
    console.debug('onDateChanged clicked', anEvent)
    let lDate = anEvent.value as Date
    this.currentDate = lDate
    this.setChart(lDate)
}

/**
*
* @param aDate
* @param aChargeUnitArray
*/
setChartDataFromEntities( aDate: Date, aChargeUnitArray: ChargeUnit[] ){
    console.debug('setChartDataFromEntities->aChargeUnitArray', aChargeUnitArray)
    let lChartDataArray = []
    let lChartDataLineDataArray: Array<number> = []
    let lChartLabelsArray: string[] = []
    //Lines and labels
    aChargeUnitArray.forEach(element => {
    lChartDataLineDataArray.push(element.charge)
    lChartLabelsArray.push(MiscHelper.dateTimeHMSForChart(element.timestamp))
    });
    //setting chart data
    lChartDataArray[0] = {
        data: lChartDataLineDataArray,
        label: MiscHelper.dateForChartTooltips(aDate),
        borderColor: Constants.CHART_DATASETS_BORDER_COLORS[0],
        backgroundColor: Constants.CHART_DATASETS_BACKGROUND_COLORS[0],// removed otherwise not working
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: 'origin'
    }

    console.debug('setChartDataFromEntities->lChartDataArray', lChartDataArray)

    this.mainChart = new Chart(ChargeUnitDailyComponent.CHART_ID, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: lChartLabelsArray,
        datasets: lChartDataArray,
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
        display: false
        },
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        },
        responsive: true,
    },

    })
    this.mainChart.update()

    let lDiff = new Date().getTime() - this.loadingDate.getTime()
    this.setStatus('Chart loaded:' + moment(lDiff).format('mm\'ss\'\''), true)
}

/**
*
*/
public resetChart(){
    this.mainChart = new Chart(ChargeUnitDailyComponent.CHART_ID, {
    type: 'line',
    fillOpacity: .3,
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: []
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
        display: true
        },
        scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true
        }],
        },
        events: ["mousemove", "mouseout", "click", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"]
    }
    })
    this.mainChart.update()
}



onRefreshClicked(anEvent){
    console.debug('onRefreshClicked', anEvent)
    this.setChart(this.currentDate)
}

onPreviousClicked(anEvent){
    console.debug('onPreviousClicked', anEvent)
    this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() - 1)
    this.dateFormControl.setValue(this.currentDate)
    this.setChart(this.currentDate)
}

onNextClicked(anEvent){
    console.debug('onNextClicked', anEvent)
    this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() + 1)
    this.dateFormControl.setValue(this.currentDate)
    this.setChart(this.currentDate)
}

}
```

### Component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
<span>
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput 
        [matDatepicker]="matDatepicker" 
        [formControl]="dateFormControl"
        (dateChange)="onDateChanged('change', $event)"
        >
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="matDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #matDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
</span>
<span class="fill-remaining-space">
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="onPreviousClicked($event)" color="accent">&lt;</button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="onNextClicked($event)" color="accent">&gt;</button>
    <button matTooltip="Refresh" mat-icon-button (click)="onRefreshClicked($event)" [disabled]="refreshButtonDisabled">
        <mat-icon svgIcon="refresh" class="mat-icon-">Refresh</mat-icon>
    </button>
</span>
<span><p>Status:{{statusMessage}}</p></span>
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="canvasContainer" style="display: block; "><!--Mandatory div including chart-->
<canvas id="canvasDaily">{{mainChart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour I figured out is that the chart creation has to be done **only one time**.

And then the properties set like `this.mainChart.data.datasets = [...]` or `this.mainChart.data.datasets.push (...)`

Otherwise there seem to be a zombie chart remaining in background and appearing on `mouseover`.

Why?? big question....